# Error inserting data into SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable
>   'Username'

The c# code:

```
SqlCommand NewUser = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [DeleteUser] Values (@username,@password,@name,@lastname,@location,@profesion,@email,@gender,@money,@pro,@xp,@lv,@m1,@m2,@m3,@m4,@m5,@d1,@d2,@d3,@d4,@d5);", c);
NewUser.Connection = c;

NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Pasword);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", FName);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", LName);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@location", Location);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@profesion", Profesion);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@money", money);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pro", property);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xp", xp);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lv", level);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m1", mission1);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m2", mission2);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m3", mission3);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m4", mission4);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@m5", mission5);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d1", did1);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d2", did2);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d3", did3);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d4", did4);
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d5", did5);

c.Open();
NewUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
c.Close();
```

Comment: Where is the definition of `Username`?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiler Error Message: CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'Username'

This error gives you when you declare the Username inside the method.  You need to assign first a default value to it before, assigning the actual value you want

Demo:

```
public void InsertMethod()
{
   string Username;
   //string Username="";      it should be like this

   MessageBox.Show(Username);// this will give you error of "unassigned local variable"
}
```

P.S.
Better to use

```
NewUser.Parameters.Add("@parameterName",SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "somevalue"
```

Than using this:

```
NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
```

This one will give you error especially when it comes to date, time and bulk insert/update.

Comment: and also, use class,properties, constructor, and method w/parameter for this kind of processes, avoid using local variables

Answer (score 0):

Username might be null

```
if (Username  == null)
{
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", DBNull.Value);
}
else
{
    NewUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Username);
}
```